# Keyboard layout switch delay

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I've just upgraded to Juno and I'm having some troubles with keyboard layout switching. When I try to switch layout (from US to RU and vice versa) with `Alt+Shift` shortcut it actually switches only after ~1 second delay. It gets really annoying while typesetting documents with two languages.

I remember fixing this somehow on Loki, but now I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I have this issue too. Delay when swith us-ru layouts. I typing couple letters in us before layout switching.
It was OK on Loki. Juno Alpha, Beta1, Beta2 and Release have this bug. Elementary Juno now is unusable for users with non-latin layout.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Especially when I swith from Russian to Latin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this script now https://github.com/yamnikov-oleg/switch-layout
Works fine!